# IS Not In Set<Id> non selective?

Tags: apex, soql

Because of the internall discussions in our development team I'm confused about filtering SOQL using Not In.

I went through [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006007&language=en_US&type=1) article. Its says that custom indexing won't be used in such cases:

> Typically, a custom index won't be used in these cases:
>               The value(s) queried for exceeds the system-defined threshold mentioned above. The filter operator is a negative operator
>   such as NOT EQUAL TO (or !=), NOT CONTAINS, and NOT STARTS WITH. The
>   CONTAINS operator is used in the filter and the number of rows to be
>   scanned exceeds 333,000. This is because the CONTAINS operator
>   requires a full scan of the index. Note that this threshold is subject
>   to change. When comparing with an empty value (Name != '').

It doesnt say anything about 'Not In' but there was one opinion that stated such query filter won't help at all and I to be sure.

```
SELECT Name from Custom__c where Id Not in :customIds
```

What's correct answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any negative filter means that *that* particular filter will not use an index (if one is available) and thus will not contribute towards making your query selective.

The best resource I think we have for this is http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf

The "Index Selectivity Exceptions" section doesn't mention `NOT IN`, but `NOT IN` does fall into the broader category of "negative filters".

You can also verify this for yourself by using the [query plan tool](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000199003&language=en_US&type=1) in the developer console.

#### +edit:

As a side note, your query may still be counted as "selective" for now. Not using an index, or not having selective filters is a red flag, but does not spell instant doom for your query in all situations. Including filters in the `WHERE` clause helps ensure that your query remains selective as your data grows. Probably the easiest way to determine whether or not a query is selective or not is to look at the `Cost` column of the query plan tool. If the lowest "Cost" of your query is over 1, your query is not selective.

Comment: Cool stuff, didnt know about Query Plan tool before, thanks!